# QueryDsl reduce expression stream

Tags: java-stream, querydsl

Here my stream of querydsl expressions:

```
Stream.of(
    Pair.of(QPatient.patient.name.any().given, Optional.ofNullable(given)),
    Pair.of(QPatient.patient.name.any().family, Optional.ofNullable(family))
)
.filter(pair -> Objects.nonNull(pair.getValue()));
```

I'd like to create a single `BooleanExpression`.

I've tried to use `BooleanBuilder`, but I don't quite figure how to collect and reduce stream items into a single `BooleanExpression`.

Shortly, without streams:

```java
BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();
booleanBuilder.and(booleanExpression1).and(booleanExpression2)...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `BooleanBuilder` in `Stream.reduce` as follows:

```java
BooleanBuilder reduce = Stream.of(
            QPatient.patient.id.isNull(),
            QPatient.patient.id.isNull()
        ).reduce(new BooleanBuilder(), BooleanBuilder::and, BooleanBuilder::and);
```

The reason that this doesn't work for you is that `BooleanBuilder` only accepts predicates and `QPair` is not a predicate (in fact, not even a boolean expression).

Also mind that `Optional.ofNullable` is never going to produce a null-value, rendering your filter useless.